# Understanding variable templates by example

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

I'm trying to understand how variable templates work by the following example:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T, const T& t>
int var = t.a;

struct T
{
    int a;
    constexpr T(): a(31){ }
};

T y;

const T t = y;

const T tt = T();

int main()
{ 
    std::cout << "var <T, t> = " << var<T, t> << std::endl;  //0
    std::cout << "y.a = " << y.a << std::endl;  //31
    std::cout <<"var <T, tt> = " << var<T, tt> << std::endl; //31
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a219d8fa8cef1741)

Honestly I have really no idea about that behavior. The thing that confused me was that the specialization `var<T, t>` is 0, but `y.a` is `31`. Also, if we initialize the object of the type `T` with temporary we also have different results. Could you clarify that a bit?

I mean, I'm looking for a normative reference from the working draft `N4296`, describing that behavior.

Comment: My wild guess is that your program has undefined behavior. Try declaring `y`, `t`, and `tt` as `constexpr`.

Comment: @AndyProwl I have the same thoughts, but unfortunately I haven't found a normative reference, describing that.

Comment: @AndyProwl BTW, g++ doesn't even accept that code. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1bb8991786ca48b5

Comment: @DmitryFucintv: [GCC only supports variable templates in v5.](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx1y.html)

Comment: @Cornstalks That's explain everything, thank you.

Comment: I̶ ̶b̶e̶l̶i̶e̶v̶e̶ ̶`T̶ ̶y̶;̶` ̶i̶s̶ ̶b̶e̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶v̶a̶l̶u̶e̶-̶i̶n̶i̶t̶i̶a̶l̶i̶z̶e̶d̶ ̶(̶w̶h̶i̶c̶h̶ ̶f̶o̶r̶ ̶g̶l̶o̶b̶a̶l̶ ̶v̶a̶r̶i̶a̶b̶l̶e̶s̶ ̶m̶e̶a̶n̶s̶ ̶a̶l̶l̶ ̶m̶e̶m̶b̶e̶r̶s̶ ̶a̶r̶e̶ ̶b̶e̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶s̶e̶t̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶z̶e̶r̶o̶)̶,̶ ̶r̶a̶t̶h̶e̶r̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶n̶ ̶d̶e̶f̶a̶u̶l̶t̶-̶c̶o̶n̶s̶t̶r̶u̶c̶t̶e̶d̶.̶

Comment: @Cornstalks: for user-defined types, value-initialization means invoking the default constructor.

Comment: @Cornstalks Well, yes, `T y` esentially is default-initialized, therefore _The applicable constructors are enumerated (13.3.1.3), and the best one for the initializer () is chosen through overload resolution (13.3)._ Don't see how this's explaing something.

Comment: @AndyProwl: Yeah, you're right. Stupid misreading on my part.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Variable templates are rather underspecified at the moment. If we go through [the current core issues list](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4304.html), we see that

- [It is unclear whether and how a variable template can be defined multiple times in a program.](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4304.html#1849)
- [It is unclear how definitions and declarations of variable templates are matched.](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4304.html#1729)
- [It is unclear how variable template partial specializations are supposed to work.](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4304.html#1711)
- [It is unclear what the point of instantiation of a variable template specialization is.](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4304.html#1845)

It also used to be unclear what initialization order variable templates follow. [CWG issue 1744](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4305.html#1744) modified [basic.start.init]/p2 to clarify that

> Dynamic initialization of a non-local variable with static storage
>   duration is  *unordered* if the variable is an implicitly or
>   explicitly instantiated specialization, and otherwise is *ordered*
>   [*Note*: an explicitly specialized static data member or variable
>   template specialization has ordered initialization. —*end note*].

`var<T, t>` is a non-local variable with static storage duration that is an implicitly instantiated specialization. Therefore its dynamic initialization is unordered. Since `t` doesn't qualify for constant initialization, that means that `var<T, t>` may be initialized before the dynamic initialization of `t`, producing 0 as a result, regardless of the relative order between `var`'s definition and `t`'s definition, and regardless of the point of instantiation of `var<T, t>`.

Thus, [moving the definition of `var` below the definition of `t`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3e2e9eff30edba3b) and/or [an explicit instantiation of `var<T, t>`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7fdc295d5dc4ae35) has no effect on what's being printed, while [providing an explicit specialization for `var<T, t>` still initializing it to `t.a`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d6976e01a09919f9) causes the first line to print `31`.

Comment: Defects in the standard aside, doesn't the statement in [basic.start.init]/2 "Dynamic initialization of a non-local variable with static storage duration is *unordered* if the variable is an
implicitly or explicitly instantiated specialization, and otherwise is *ordered*." apply here? `var<T, t>` is both "a non-local variable with static storage duration" and "an implicitly instantiated specialization."

Comment: @Casey Hmm, that's not in N4140, which I use for C++14. Is it from N4296?

Comment: @Casey found it. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4305.html#1744

Comment: [Approved at the November meeting as CWG motion 1 and applied to the working draft](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/commit/a0c45aa53cfd690831969eb8cf3b4a4be0388871#diff-a7cb4634eeb2e4ce984d41aaa9a70ef4L2563).

Comment: Just to clarify, _Dynamic initialization of a non-local variable with static storage duration is unordered if the variable is an implicitly or explicitly instantiated specialization, and otherwise is ordered_, that's only variable tamplates may have unordered iinitialization.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv It also includes static data members of class templates.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is the order of initialization:

- First is zero initialization. All three variables are set to zero.
- Then is constant initialization. `y` and `tt` are initialized using `constexpr` which yields 31.
- Dynamic initialization is the last one. In this step, the order of variables in the compilation unit is important. `var` is before `t` and so `var<T, t>` is initialized from `t` before `t` is initialized from `y`.

Comment: Initialization is not a multi-pass procedure.

Comment: @AndyProwl: Yes it is. [basic.start.init] describes it in gory detail, and this is a decent summary.

Comment: Yep, sorry everyone. I derped.

Comment: I edited the answer because I wasn't allowed to retract my incorrect downvote otherwise. Feel free to revert to the original version.

Comment: `y` qualifies for constant initialization, like `tt`, because the default constructor is `constexpr`. `t` doesn't. The issue is the relative order of the initialization of `t` and `var<T, t>`.

Comment: T.C. You are right! I see the problem and will edit the answer.

Comment: [Moving `var` below `t`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3e2e9eff30edba3b) doesn't do anything. I think clang is probably following the same rules as those for class template static data members - those have unordered initialization.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, the `var` specialisations are dynamically initialised before the other global variables. In that case, `t` needs dynamic initialisation (since it's initialiser isn't a constant expression), so still has a zero value when used to initialise `var<T, t>`; while `tt` can be statically initialised from its `constexpr` initialiser, so has its final value when used to initialise `var<T, tt>`.

However, I can't find anything in the [draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) to say whether this is expected (as it would be if the point of declaration of the specialisations were that of the template itself), or undefined/incorrect behaviour.

Comment: [Thinking aloud]: OTOH, the behavior does not change if `y` is declared as `const`. I guess that's not sufficient to guarantee compile-time initialization through the `constexpr` constructor though.

Comment: @AndyProwl: I guess you mean `y`. It would have to be `constexpr`, not just `const`, to be usable in a constant expression (integers and enumerations can be used if they're just `const`, but not other types).

Comment: [CWG issue 1845](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1845). A quick search through the issue list seems to show that variable templates are underspecified in many other ways.